# Retrieve bounceCount, addedDate, addedBy, addMethod properties of subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I've got stuck at getting these properties from a "Subscriber" object. The following is my code in which they are marked as "unknown":

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < subscriberList.size(); i++) {
Subscriber subscriber = subscriberList.get(i);

JSONObject jsoDataChild = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

jsoDataChild.put("id", subscriber.getID());
jsoDataChild.put("status", subscriber.getStatus().toString());
jsoDataChild.put("unsubscribeDate", subscriber.getID());    
jsoDataChild.put("bounceCount", "Unknown");
jsoDataChild.put("modifiedDate", subscriber.getModifiedDate() + "");
jsoDataChild.put("addedBy", "Unknown");
jsoDataChild.put("addMethod", "Unknown");
jsoDataChild.put("addedDate", "Unknown");
jsoDataChild.put("createdDate", subscriber.getCreatedDate() + "");                      
jsoDataChild.put("subscriberKey", subscriber.getSubscriberKey());               
jsoDataChild.put("emailAddress", subscriber.getEmailAddress()); 
...
```

I've tried many ways but they all failed. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this using the JAVA SDK?

Comment: Yes, you're correct!